# how to use google Analitycs in ios, without extending the library GAITrackedViewController in all library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want this library is not exteneder all my classes but one extended to all

@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be extending it in every class. You just need to register your `GAITracker` in your appDelegate and then send events to it from inside your viewControllers. Its a singleton, so all you have to do is import it and call your defaultTracker in each viewController you want to send events from.

Inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your AppDelegate.m:

```
GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"yourID"];
```

And then in each of your viewControllers you want to track events in, just do:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"yourViewControllerName" withAction:@"somethingHappened" withLabel:@"yourLabel" withValue:@1];
```